# translation and rotating at the same time and waiting before animation?

Tags: unity, c#

I am having difficulties here. I want to move my character with the buttons and I want the character to rotate wherever he is going.

Also I want to play an animation when there is no keys pressed. I am able to do that but I want the animation to play after 10 seconds of no key being pressed, and only once. Than after a movement that resets and again after 10 seconds of no key the animation plays. (The animation works but it happens right after I stop pressing a key and continuously.)

```
IEnumerator Test()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10.0f);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate((Vector3.forward) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.Log("Pressing W key");
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate((Vector3.back) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.Log("Pressing s key");
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * rotateSpeed);
        Debug.Log("Pressing a key");
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotateSpeed);
        Debug.Log("pressed D");
    }
    if (!Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        moveSpeed = 20;
    }

    if (!Input.anyKey)
    {
        if (counter >= 2)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Test());
            anim.Play("Animation");
            counter = 0;
            Debug.Log("A key or mouse click has been detected");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a more simple way, like this:

```
float lastKeyPressedTime;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.anyKey )
         lastKeyPressedTime = Time.time;

    if(lastKeyPressedTime + 10f < Time.time ) 
    {
        PlayAnimation();
        lastKeyPressedTime = Time.time;
    }
}
```

About the animation, don't forget to uncheck the Loop checkbox in Inspector